# what is type of this RoHS LCD ( Any datasheet)?

Tags: lcd, proteus, model

I have one  18 pin LCD with this information:
1Qcu099-FLYG-GBW
So i don't know what type of the LCD is this and have not find any datasheet form google, So It's picture is here:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

If have more information for It's model in Proteus and any driver library for AVR micro's or any datasheet, will be very useful for us.

Edited:

Dose it datasheet is here:
[wh2004l](http://www.unisystem.pl/download/produkty/2011/wh2004l-yyk-et_xAXCw/WH2004L-YYK-ET%23.pdf)

if yes, so any AVR library for running it's (wh2004l) with ST7066 Controller IC ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Scrap it and buy one with data.

Comment: @LeonHeller - these kind of things are typically similar enough that if one already has the part in hand and it isn't a professional (time and materials both funded) project it can be worth giving it a try based on the data of something similar.  Even then, for a one-off need, overnight shipping means the earliest something works is tomorrow, while the part on hand could well end up working today.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet indicates that this display -- like most small LCD character displays -- implements an interface compatible with the [Hitachi HD44780 controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller). There are two extra pins on this part (17 and 18), but they can both be safely left disconnected.

This interface is implemented by the [Arduino LiquidCrystal library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal).

Note that RoHS is not a brand name -- it's an inspection mark, indicating that the board (probably) meets the European [Restriction of Hazardous Substances directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Hazardous_Substances_Directive) by not containing any lead, mercury, cadmium, or certain other toxins.